# Regex /Perl : Match all instances of any string between two specified strings

Tags: regex, string, perl

I need to find all strings that occur between the words "Close" and "Minor", for example, but the words "Close" and "Minor" occur many times in my string. How can I use regex to find all of the strings between each instance of "Close" and "Minor". Example:

In the text

```
$string = "Minor fall major fifth Close to home Minors cannot vote before 18 Polls Close at 8";
```

I want to match

```
 fall major fifth
```

and

`s cannot vote before 18 Polls`

I have tried to use this:

```
my @matches = $string =~ /Minor(.*) Close/gi;
```

but this matches

```
Minor fall major fifth Close to home Minors cannot vote before 18 Polls Close
```

which matches the words themselves, and does not produce the desired match.

I'm so lost!

Comment: I'm fascinated to know what strings you're expecting. Your example reads like the lyrics of "Hallelujah": ***The minor fall and the major lift / The baffled king composing "Hallelujah"***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a non-greedy quantifier:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $string = "Minor fall major fifth Close to home Minors cannot vote before 18 Polls Close at 8";

my @matches = $string =~ /Minor(.*?) Close/gi;

say for @matches;
```

Outputs:

```
 fall major fifth
s cannot vote before 18 Polls
```

Comment: this helps a ton, but I'm still matching the words themselves. I should be able to fix that on my own though